# How to create array from Model?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im new to javascript and I have this code where I should pass or convert to jQuery. I have tried some code but it doesn't work. How can I do it properly?

Here is what it should look like:

```
<script>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2017-10-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Juan Dela Cruz',
            start: '2017-10-01T10:30:00',

        },
        {
            title: 'Juan Dela Cruz',
            start: '2017-10-12T10:30:00',

        },
        {
            title: 'Juan Dela Cruz',
            start: '2017-10-27T12:00:00'
        }
    ]
});
```

and here is what I have tried:

```
<script>
var x = [];
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @:x.push(title='@Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.Patient.LastName)', start='@Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.ScheduleDate)')
}
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2017-10-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: x
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: This looks less a jQuery issue and more a Razor outputting issue.

Comment: You can use `var x = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => new { title = x.Patient.LastName, start = x.ScheduleDate)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're iterating correct the `Model` using `@foreach` statement.

The problem is at this line:

```
@:x.push(title='@Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.Patient.LastName)', start='@Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.ScheduleDate)')
```

You have to **push** an `object` in following way:

```
@:x.push({title:'@item.Patient.LastName', start:'@item.ScheduleDate'});
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `foreach in jQuery` is `$.each` and this a simple sample to do that :

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```